# fix width of table layout

Tags: html, tablelayout

Can someone please help me, this is driving me crazy. I have seen answers to other questions on this site, but I just cant seem to apply them.

Basically I am trying to fix the widths of my tables in html dreamweaver. However it just doesnt seem to work.

My current code looks like this:

```
table align="center" style='table-layout:fixed'  width="910" height="627" border="0"
```

but it still expands above the specified width.

I have tried also to do this this:

```
.fixed { table-layout: fixed; }

 <td width="18" class="fixed"></td>
```

but that doesnt work either!

Answer (score 1):

You could try putting all the styles you need in a class,

```
.fixed { table-layout: fixed; width: 910px; height: 627px; border: none; text-align: center;}
```

then just apply the class to the table:

```
<table class="fixed">
```

Also, could you clarify what you mean by "trying to fix the widths" in your table? Could you post some more of the code around the table, or the entire table itself?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like this.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;width:910px">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Or you can give overflow:scroll if you need a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do: get rid of the HTML4-attributes like `align`, `width` or `border` and do this with CSS alone. It should be no problem to set an absolute width to a table.

Second, you don't need a `table-layout: fixed;` to set a fixed width for a table. `<table style="width: 910px;">` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.....I am quite new to this,  but I will try to expand

Basically, below is my style sheet and start of code. I want, the body, and the top to tables to be a maximum width of 910.  I am creating other tables inside of these, and when information is entered into the cells, it doesn’t wrap around, it just makes the page a bigger width…..I don’t want this to be possible

```
<style type="text/css"> 
body {  background-color: #000;font-family: Comic Sans MS, cursive;font-size:    12px;color: #000;text-align:left 
    width="910" height="627" border="0" } 

.mainbody {background-color: #fff;width="844px" table-layout: fixed;} 
.background {background-color: #000;} 

.banner_f { color: #FFFFFF;font-weight: bold;font-size: 36px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        width="910" height="203" table-layout: fixed;} 

</style>
```

'/Images/Buttons/Fixtures_Top.jpg','/Images/Buttons/Scorers_Top.jpg','/Images/Buttons/Reports_Top.jpg','/Images/Buttons/Contact_Top.jpg')"> 
     
     
     
    
  width="844" height="68"> 
      
    `